# p:autoComplete not firing p:ajax event

Tags: java, ajax, primefaces, autocomplete

I had this issue for a few hours and I surfed the net to try and find the solution but unfortunately I came up short.

Here is what I want to do.

I want to set p:outputText values when item in my autoComplete gets selected.

Here is the code:

```
<p:autoComplete 
               completeMethod="#{dynamicSearchBean.getCustomers}"
               minQueryLength="1">

               <p:ajax event="itemSelect" 
               listener="#{dynamicSearchBean.handleSelection}" 
               update="addName"/>
</p:autoComplete>

<h:outputText id="addName" value="#{dynamicSearchBean.firstName}"/>
```

And the backing bean:

```
public void handleSelection(SelectEvent event)
{
    String value = (String) event.getObject();
    System.out.println("selected "+value);

}//end method handleSelection
```

My autoComplete is working fine by getting values from DB but no event is being triggered when I select the value, and that is the main issue here.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I did not specify that even is not fired when item is selected with mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public void handleSelection(SelectEvent event)
{
    String value = (String) event.getObject();
    this.firstName=value;

}//end method handleSelection
```

Comment: Reason I used print is just to print to console if stuff was correct. It prints when item is selected using Enter key but not when it is clicked with mouse. itemSelect should work with both no?

Comment: @RoMEJA the change in code will set it the value to your outputText